# Selecting all users of the same company of current user

Tags: mysql, select, reserved-words

I have a little mixed up!

Current user's id is stored in session.

I want to select all the users that have the same `company_id` of current user.

**`company_id` is a field in `user` table.**

The query that doesn't work:

```
SELECT `all_users`.`id`, `all_users`.`username`, `all_users`.`fullname`
FROM (`user` current_user)
JOIN `company` c ON `c`.`id` = `current_user`.`company_id`
JOIN `user` all_users ON `all_users`.`company_id` = `c`.`id`
WHERE `current_user`.`id` = <<<$current_user_id>>>
```

**Error:**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'current_user) JOIN `company` c ON `c`.`id` = `current_user`.`company_id` JOIN `u'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`current _user`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) is a reserved keyword in MySQL.

You need to escape it in your query to mark it as a table alias.

Use backtick in your query. Like so:

```
SELECT `all_users`.`id`, `all_users`.`username`, `all_users`.`fullname`
FROM `user` `current_user`
JOIN `company` c ON `c`.`id` = `current_user`.`company_id`
JOIN `user` all_users ON `all_users`.`company_id` = `c`.`id`
WHERE `current_user`.`id` = <<<$current_user_id>>>
```

Comment: My GOD!!!!! Thank you very much. The query was outputted by codeigniter's active record. Thank you @DreamEater!

Comment: @smhnaji Dunno why you are using `current_user` as an alias for `user`. You've to type a deal more. :P

Comment: yes, maybe it was not a good idea at all. Thank you anyway.

Comment: We could even avoid `join` the `company` table! http://stackoverflow.com/a/15331484/315550

Comment: @smhnaji Rather, avoid joining the `all_users` alias for `user` table.

Comment: I think there should be a problem. Simply this will not work because `all_users` is not defined in the last edit; is that? There IS a way to avoid `join`ing `company` table, but it looks that we need TWO instances of `user` with different aliases as my answer states.

Comment: @smhnaji Oh, sorry about that. Fixed now.

Comment: unfortunately current query is the same as `SELECT u.id, u.username, u.fullname FROM user u WHERE u.id = $current_user_id`. There is absolutely no need to the join in this situation and also it doesn't return what it's supposed to be.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25959/discussion-between-dream-eater-and-smhnaji)

Answer (score 1):

I think that it had a very simpler solution!

```
SELECT `all_users`.`id`, `all_users`.`username`, `all_users`.`fullname`
FROM (`user` u)
JOIN `user` all_users ON `u`.`company_id` = `all_users`.`company_id`
WHERE `u`.`id` = <<<$current_user_id>>>
```

Less `join`, more optimized, same result!

Answer (score 0):

You should get the session user's company id to make this a lot easier on yourself and the db.

```
select * from all_users u left join company c on u.company_id = c.id WHERE u.company_id = current_user_id.company_id
```

Something like this should work just fine.

Comment: Obviously wrong. But thank you for your try.

Comment: Sorry but why is it wrong?

Comment: You didn't define `current_user_id` table.

Comment: I mentioned that he should get session user's company id. As in a php variable.

Comment: @sas1ni69 `current_user_id` would give a number like `3`. And for sure `u.company_id = 3.company_id` cannot be right.